# How to show the sum of the total results and the result each of the output sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sqlplus, ora-00937

I am trying to display the total sum of the Total output cost of the invoice: These are the tables with italics columns representing primary keys:
Customer:

```
| name | *cust#* |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Radio Spares   |     c1       |
| Pyramid| c2            |
```

Item:

```
| *item#* | iname | price      |      
| -------- | -------------- | ----------
| i1    | CD          |  1        |
| i2   | DVD          | 2 |
```

StandingOrder:

```
| *so#* | cust# | item#      |      
| -------- | -------------- | ----------
| so1    | c1          |  i1        |
| so2   | c2          | i2 |
```

Invoice:

```
| *in#* | cust# |
| -------- | -------------- |
| i1    | c1       |
| i2   | c2         |
```

Delivery:

```
| *d#* | in#      |      
| -------- | -------------- |
| d1    |   1        |
| d2   | 2 |
| d3    |   1        |
| d4   | 2 |
| d5    |   1        |
| d6   | 2 |
```

Dquantity:

```
| so# | d#      | quantity |    
| -------- | -------------- | -----|
| d1    |   1        | 1|
| d2   | 2 | 2|
| d3    |   1        | 1|
| d4   | 2 | 2|
| d5    |   1        | 1|
| d6   | 2 | 2|
```

I want to find: the sum of the total cost after of the requested output:

```
distinct cu.name as customer_name,
dq.d# as delivery_no,
item.item# as item_no,
item.iname as description,
dq.quantity as quantity,
item.price as item_price,
item.price*dq.quantity as cost,
sum(item.price*dq.quantity) as sum
from customer cu
inner join standingorder sor on cu.cust#=sor.cust#
inner join dquantity dq on sor.order#=dq.order#
inner join invoice iv on cu.cust#=iv.cust#
inner join delivery dl on iv.inv#=dl.inv#
inner join item on sor.item#=item.item#
where cu.cust# = 'c2';
```

but when I do, I am given ORA-00937: not a single-group group function. but if i removed

```
sum(item.price*dq.quantity) as sum
```

It runs but without the total sum, which I need.
So in this case: where cu.cust# = 'c1' the sum would be 3 and 'c2' the sum is 12.

What I would like to see: for c2:

```
CUSTOMER_NAME            DELIVE ITEM_N IName            QUANTITY
------------------------ ------ ------ -------------------- ----------
ITEM_PRICE       COST 
---------- ----------
Pyramid             D2    I2     DVD                         2
      2      4

                    D4     I2     DVD                        2
      2      4

                    D6    I2     DVD                         2
      2      4

Sum
---
12
```

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It would be helpful to show the results you would like to see. I'm not sure what you want to do with the `sum` value.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need a `group by`:

```
select cu.name as customer_name, dq.d# as delivery_no,
       sum(item.price*dq.quantity) as sum
from . . .
where cu.cust# = 'c2'
group by cu.name, dq.d#;
```

This returns the total per delivery.  It removes all the item specific information -- because that would probably return too many rows.

If you want the total per customer, then remove the delivery as well:

```
select cu.name as customer_name
       sum(item.price*dq.quantity) as sum
from . . .
where cu.cust# = 'c2'
group by cu.name;
```

EDIT:

If you just want the total -- which is the same -- on all rows then use window/analytic functions:

```
select . . . , -- all the columns you want
       sum(item.price * dq.quantity) over (partition by cu.cust#) as customer_total
from . . .
```

Comment: What i am trying to do is show the total sum of the results which is missing from the output, by doing what you gave it just give me an ORA-00979 error, NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION. can you clarify further?

Comment: I tried your code in edit, but customer_total gives is not 12 for cust#='c2', could you clarify that?

Comment: @JoeLiu . . . Your code is probably generating duplicates, presumably due to multiple deliveries for an order.

Comment: that is exactly what i want, but I only want the sum amount to be the sum of the cost

Answer (score 0):

All columns that aren't aggregated must be contained in the `GROUP BY` clause. For example (a simple one):

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> select deptno, job, sum(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  /
select deptno, job, sum(sal)
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Add the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SQL> select deptno, job, sum(sal)
  2  from emp
  3  group by deptno ,job;

    DEPTNO JOB         SUM(SAL)
---------- --------- ----------
        20 CLERK            920
        30 SALESMAN        5600
        20 MANAGER         2975
        30 CLERK            950
        10 PRESIDENT      10000
        30 MANAGER         2850
        20 PRESIDENT       1100
        10 CLERK           1300
        10 MANAGER         2450
        20 ANALYST         6000

10 rows selected.
```

Alternatively, see if `sum` - in its analytic form - does what you want:

```
SQL> select deptno, job,
  2    sum(sal) over (partition by deptno order by null) sumsal
  3  from emp;

    DEPTNO JOB           SUMSAL
---------- --------- ----------
        10 MANAGER        13750
        10 PRESIDENT      13750
        10 CLERK          13750
        20 MANAGER        10995
        20 ANALYST        10995
        20 PRESIDENT      10995
        20 CLERK          10995
        20 ANALYST        10995
        30 SALESMAN        9400
        30 SALESMAN        9400
        30 SALESMAN        9400
        30 CLERK           9400
        30 MANAGER         9400
        30 SALESMAN        9400

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```